# Box model difference between IE8 and IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, css

Recently, I realized that IE8 renders a box just like in "Quirks Mode", while in IE9, there is no trouble, same as other modern browsers.

Here are screenshots for how IE renders a box in 8 and 9:

```
<div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid red; padding: 2px; margin 3px; background: #333;">
</div>
```

[image: How IE8 renders]
[image: How IE9 renders]

My questions is how can I let IE8 render box like the way in IE9, thanks?

Comment: I don't see a difference in the two images?

Comment: Are you using the correct doctype?

Comment: @xec Sorry, corrected the screenshot.

Comment: @cimmanon I am sure the Doctype is correct.
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Comment: It seems that something causes your IE8 to switch to Quirks mode.  What does `document.compatMode` say if you check it in the script on that page?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn CSS1Compat

Answer (score 0):

for IE8 use [**`box-sizing: border-box;`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) on your `div`.

also: your missing a `:` between `margin` and `3px`.
and as best practice: separate your styling from your markup.

Comment: sorry for the typo, I put the style that way just for testing. This will "fix" the problem, but does this mean IE8 box-model is still the older one?

Comment: emm.. I'm not sure. read [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/147587/the-box-model-internet-explorer-vs-w3c) for more info.